# Red, Green and Blue value arrays to color bitmap

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, rgb

I'm trying to create a bitmap from separate Red, Green, and blue arrays so I can use this bitmap later to create a frame for an avi file (SharpAVI). I've tried the following code which works:

```
Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);   
for (int ii = 0; ii < (Width*Height); ii++)
{
    ypos = ii / Width;
    xpos = ii % Width;
    Bmp.SetPixel(xpos, ypos, Color.FromArgb(dataR[ii], dataG[ii], dataB[ii]));
}
```

the arrays dataR, dataG, and dataB contain the values (0 to 255) of the colors starting from 0,0 and ending on width,height. However, this code is rather slow. I would prefer to directly produce the bitmap from the data, but I'm not sure how. I've seached around and found something in the direction of:

```
Bitmap bm_Image = new Bitmap(Width, Height, Stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ipPtrRGB);
```

but I don't fully understand how this works. I've read something about padding the data etc. Does anybody know a method to do this fast?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792723/adding-or-subtracting-color-from-an-image-in-a-picturebox-using-c-sharp/28799612?s=9|0.3049#28799612) for an example of using lockbits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with bitmaps faster, I would suggest using this LockBitmap class, found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

The implementation is relatively simple, and you can use the same data structures that you are using at the moment. This is what the `LockBitmap` implementation will look like for your code:

```
Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
LockBitmap lockBitmap = new LockBitmap(Bmp);
lockBitmap.LockBits();
for (int ii = 0; ii < (Width*Height); ii++)
{
    ypos = ii / Width;
    xpos = ii % Width;    
    lockBitmap.SetPixel(xpos, ypos, Color.FromArgb(dataR[ii], dataG[ii], dataB[ii]));
}
lockBitmap.UnlockBits();
Bmp.Save(filename)
```

I've used this class myself for a few projects, and I found it to be much faster than the standard .NET functions. The link above even has a benchmark test you can run to see how much faster it is.

Comment: The `SetPixel` I'm using in the example is actually a function of the `LockBitmap` class in the link - it's not the same as `Bitmap.SetPixel` at all, it just has the same name!

Comment: Ah, interesting. so it is an alternative to setting the channels directly. (Nice avatar btw ;-) - I don't think the division is a good idea though!

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you very much! Where my previous code used 250ms to store a 800x500 picture, it now uses only around 50ms. @TaW why do you think the division is a bad idea? I thought it was an easy way to get the right index for the x and y positions.

Comment: The usualy way is to use a double loop with only additions in it. But the (by far) bigger gain over integer division is using lockbits..